# Can I capture some things by reference and others by value in a closure?

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

Presume we have the following code, where I defined a closure named `closure`. Within this closure, I want to use the outer `x` by immutable reference (`&T`), and at the same time, using `y` by taking ownership. How can I do that? If I use `move`, all the outer variables that used in the closure will be moved into the closure. And also here the outer variable `y` is copyable.

```
let x: i32 = 1;
let y: i32 = 2;
let closure = || {
    println!("{}", x);  // make sure x is used by &T.
    // println!("{}", y);  // how can I use y by taking its ownership?
};
closure();
```

Comment: jut add a `let x = &x;` line before your closure ?

Comment: Here are some other questions with answers that mention the same idea: [Why is the value moved into the closure here rather than borrowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38913472/3650362) and [Mutably borrow one struct field while borrowing another in a closure](/q/36379242/3650362)

Answer (score 19):

Note that capturing by moving a reference is equal to capturing by reference.

When you add a `move` keyword to the closure, yes, everything is captured by moving. But you can move a reference instead, which is what a closure without a `move` keyword does.

```rust
let x: i32 = 1;
let y: i32 = 2;
let closure = {
    let x = &x;
    move || {
        println!("{}", x);  // borrowing (outer) x
        println!("{}", y);  // taking the ownership of y
    }
};
closure();
```

Comment: Another useful idiom is to open a scope to create the closure, and use `let x = &x` to force borrowing in an otherwise `move` closure: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e241b2b4394dcdcb715c9ef4bdba919

Comment: @user4815162342 Nice practice! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks; I've gone ahead and updated the comment accordingly.