# Do Rust closures capture context by reference or by value?

Tags: rust

C++

```cpp
const auto it = vector.find([&activity](const std::string & r) {
    return activity == r;
});
```

Rust

```
let index = match vector.iter().position(|r| r == activity) {
    Some(x) => x,
    None => {
        vector.push(activity.to_string());
        vector.len() - 1
    },
};
```

I'm a Rust novice from C++, I was wondering if the lambda in the C++ snippet which captures the variable `activity` by reference and the item argument of the vector as a reference parameter is equivalent to the closure of the rust snippet below. In other words, does the closure in the Rust snippet have both arguments as references as well?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C++ lambdas, but this closure will use references for both `r` and `activity`. I can tell because `vector.iter()` will iterate through immutable references to elements in `vector` (As opposed to `iter_mut` for mutable references and `into_iter` for deconstructing the `vector` into owned values). And for `activity`, I know it is a reference since you explicitly use `&activity`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the value moved into the closure here rather than borrowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913472/why-is-the-value-moved-into-the-closure-here-rather-than-borrowed)

Comment: @Locke Just to be clear, `r` is not a captured variable and so isn't particularly relevant to the question. (It _is_ a reference because `vector` is presumably a `Vec<_>`, but it doesn't matter to the question.)

Answer (score 2):

In short, closures capture by reference when they can, and move when they must. The preferences for capture is by the following order, first available option is used:

- Immutable borrow (`&T`).
- Unique immutable borrow (no syntax for that). This is used when the closure assigns to the captured variable but does not take a mutable reference to it (explicitly or implicitly, using method autoref). See [this section on the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#unique-immutable-borrows-in-captures) for more.
- Mutable borrows (`&mut T`).
- Move or copy (`T`).

If the closure specifies the `move` keyword, however, all captured variables are always moved/copied. This is usually used when the closure needs to outlive the captured variable, e.g. when it is returned from the function.

In your example, since `r == activity` desugars into `PartialEq::eq(&r, &activity)`, `activity` is captured by immutable reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, lambdas (called closures btw) have other subtleties than capture by value or by reference. The *real* question to be asked is: does the lambda have the *ownership* of the variable, or did it just *borrow* it (which is not quite the same). If you looked only at the compiled result, taking the *ownership* is like moving by value, and *borrowing* is like taking by reference.

By default, they only *borrow* the variable, and if you want them to take the ownership you have to use the `move` keyword. However, there are several types of *borrow*s (mutable vs. read-only), contrasting with *take by reference* of C++, of which there is only one kind.
See the [appropriate section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-the-environment-with-closures) of the Rust book for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: ‘have ownership’ vs ‘borrow’ is the exact same subtlety as ‘by value’ vs ‘by reference’ (differing only in that values are moved, not copied)

Comment: Yes, but no, in the sense that in the Rust world too, it makes sense to say 'by value' or 'by reference'. 'ownership' and 'borrow' have a different meaning, because they do not only reference to what actually happens in the memory, but they also imply certain assumptions the compiler make. A borrow in Rust is not a pointer (both exist, although once compiled you can't tell if it was a borrow or a pointer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one remark a reference in c++ is not of one kind. You may take a reference or a reference to constant which maps to mutabl vs immutable object

Comment: @mkmostafa The distinction is subtle, but it's there. The C++ concept of a reference largely can ignore the underlying type. Whether it's `T` or `const T` doesn't fundamentally change the way the reference behaves. In C++, a `& T` and a `& const T` are both references with different referent types. In Rust, a `&mut T` and a `&T` are _different kinds of references altogether._